# gFolderDisplay and other build-in globals not defined in Thunderbird background script

Tags: thunderbird

As a first step of a Thunderbird WebExtension i am trying to post the number of selected mails in the console window. For that i use a button in the main window which once pressed calls a function in the background script which should post a message showing the number of selected mails. But it seems that the global gFolderDisplay.selectedCount is not recognized in the background script. Also browser.gFolderDisplay.selectedCount doesn't work. The same code works perfectly when executed in the Thunderbird scratchpad. Why is the code working in the scratchpad but not in the background script? Are they not working in the same context?

I know that the button is working, because i can for example open another tab if the button is pressed.
The code line console.log("Selected Mails:" + gFolderDisplay.selectedCount); is perfectly working in the scratchpad but not in the background script.

My background.js:

```
function test_some_stuff() {
    console.log("Selected Mails:" + gFolderDisplay.selectedCount);
}

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(test_some_stuff);
```

My manifest.json:

```
{

  "description": "Demonstrating toolbar buttons",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "button-demo",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
       "16": "icons/page-16.png",
       "32": "icons/page-32.png"
    }
  },

  "permissions": [
      "*://developer.mozilla.org/*",
      "webRequest",
      "accountsRead",
      "accountsFolders",
      "messagesRead",
      "messagesMove",
      "webNavigation"
  ]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird v68+ uses the new extensions standard called [MailExtensions](https://developer.thunderbird.net/add-ons/about-add-ons#mailextensions), which is based on the WebExtensions standard, and most of the old API is not supported natively anymore.

Since this is a transition period until June 2020 I think (new API is not fully developed yet), in the meantime you can use some of the old API using the [WebExtension Experiments](https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/68/how-to/experiments.html).

I'm struggling with the same thing, but I got some useful replies on the [Thunderbird extension development discussion](https://thunderbird.topicbox.com/groups/addons/T429431ffedb81e8e-Md367e81ee6d1159ccb4f087c), check it out.

**UPDATE:** The last reply I got is:

> `gFolderDisplay` is a variable on each main Thunderbird window, you need to find the right one first. The extension api does not run in the window context.
>
> See the implementation of the mailTabs api for some details.